# Update object attribute with one click in django

Tags: python, html, django

I have a simple model which had three attributes A B & C
While creating the object i have kep the value of attibute to be 'null true' 
So the model object is being displayed in my template and i want to put a simple link below the object which will pass on the current time value to the objects attribute whenever clicked. just like a stop watch.

How can i do it?

**model**

```
class track(models.Model):<br>
      task = models.CharField(max_length=1000)<br>
      starttime = models.TimeField(null=True,blank=True)<br>
      endtime = models.TimeField(null=True,blank=True)<br>
      date = models.DateField(default = datetime.datetime.now())<br>
```

**template**

```
{%for x in tracks%}<br>
{{ x.task }}<br>
<i>link</i> (clicking this will auomatically set starttime attribute to current system time.)<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Updating the object value without refreshing the page?

Comment: best option is to use ajax requests. if you post code you have tried, i'm sure someone will help with a more specific solution.